# unable to connect to online websocket

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I built a web socket with ratchet and it works fine on my local system (connecting the client to ws:localhost) but doesn't on an online server. The server starts but i'm not able to make connection to it. I'm not sure if its a port issue but below is my code for the server.php

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
),
8080, '0.0.0.0'
);

$server->run();
```

Comment: Most hosts will block ports that aren't 80 or 443 by default. You will probably have to add a rule to your security group or firewall that will allow port 8080 to the internet.

Comment: Thanks i already fixed it.  I was making use of a shared host which didn't allow me bind to port 8080 but now i'm using a vps (amazon aws) and its working fine